# Probability of an event happening out of three

Tags: probability

I need help.

> When voting for 3 different candidates, one has 60% chance of winning, the other has 75% and the third one 37.5%, what is the probability that at least one of the candidates will win the election?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow impressive.  Not sure how the percentages can add up to more than 100% if it is for the same election.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Are they in three different elections?

Comment: Usually these type of "at least one" word problems are solved by taking 1 minus the prob that all will not happen so 1 - (0.4 * 0.25 * 0.625) = 93.75%

Comment: It's all for the same election but different positions; one is a governor, senator & county supervisor. I tried 1-P(not happening) but my results are not in the answer choices. The results are in fractions.

Comment: @David. It could be three elections, or it could be one election (as for a city council or school board) in which more than one candidate wins. In the latter case, it is especially important to ask about independence because the applicable multiplication rule assumes independence. Possibly a poor question, possibly an imprecise paraphrase.

Comment: Thank you, I can now see where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: It's one minus the probability that none of them win

Comment: Very simple?  How do the percentages add up to more than 100% then?

Answer (score 1):

I will not give the answer because you have shown nothing about
your own thoughts. Here is a method that will work, *assuming that the three
events are independent.*  First, for each candidate, what is the
probability he/she *loses*. Second, what is the probability *all
three lose*? Third, what is the probability *at least one wins.*

Comment: Why do the events have to be independent?